# racket: Why doesn't apply work with "bitmap" function?

Tags: scheme, lisp, racket, eval, apply

I have been cautioned against using `eval` in my code.  However, in this bit of racket code, I can get `eval` working but not something more recommended, like `apply`.  Here is the code:

```
(require 2htdp/image)
(define (get_img filename)
  (let ([img (eval `(bitmap ,filename))])
    (image->color-list mask)
  ))
```

I tried doing the naive replace of eval with apply:

```
(require 2htdp/image)
(define (get_img filename)
  (let ([img (apply `(bitmap ,filename))])
    (image->color-list mask)
  ))
```

and when I run it I get:

```
; apply: arity mismatch;
;  the expected number of arguments does not match the given number
;   expected: at least 2
;   given: 1
; [,bt for context]
```

I have tried a few permutations of this code, but to no avail.  I was hopeful this one

```
(let ([img (apply bitmap `(filename))])
 (image->color-list img)`)
```

would work, but clearly there's still something I'm not understanding

## EDIT:

The first thing I tried, with error message:

```
> (require 2htdp/image)
> (define (get_img filename)
    (let ([img (bitmap filename)])
      (image->color-list img)))
; readline-input:6:15: bitmap: expected a path with a / in it
;   in: (bitmap filename)
; [,bt for context]
```

Another failed attempt:

```
> (define (get_img filename)
    (let ([img (apply bitmap (list filename))])
      (image->color-list mask)))
; readline-input:16:20: bitmap: bad syntax
;   in: bitmap
; [,bt for context]
```

Comment: Looking at the [docs](https://docs.racket-lang.org/teachpack/2htdpimage.html#(part._.Bitmaps)), it seems like `(let ([img (bitmap/file filename)]) ...)` should work. [`bitmap`](https://docs.racket-lang.org/teachpack/2htdpimage.html#%28form._%28%28lib._2htdp%2Fimage..rkt%29._bitmap%29%29) is a macro that treats symbols differently from literal strings.

Answer (score 3):

You're using it wrong. So behind the variable `+` there is a procedure object which can be applied. These are equal:

```
(+ (* 2 3) 5)              ; ==> 11
(apply + (list (* 2 3) 5)) ; ==> 11
(apply + `(,(* 2 3) 5))    ; ==> 11
```

In your example you are using `bitmap` and it isn't a procedure at all but a macro and it seems it is to get bitmaps from a racket package and with strings it expects at least a slash since images should't be in the package root. You should replace it with [`bitmap/file`](https://docs.racket-lang.org/teachpack/2htdpimage.html#%28def._%28%28lib._2htdp%2Fimage..rkt%29._bitmap%2Ffile%29%29) which is a procedure and takes a file path absolute or relative to current working directory instead.

In your example `` (apply `(bitmap/file ,filename) `` you are passing apply a list as first argument instead of a procedure object and a last argument with parameters.

In your example `` (apply bitmap/file `(filename)) `` you are applying `bitmap` with a literal list with a symbol `filename` which has nothing to do with the variable with the same name. You were so close since I think you wanted `` (apply bitmap/file `(,filename)) `` which is a funny way of doing `(apply bitmap/file (list filename))`. What I don't understand is why can't you just do this:

```
(define (get_img filename)
  (let ([img (bitmap/file filename)])
    (image->color-list mask)))
```

Comment: In fact, your `(apply bitmap (list filename))` suggestion didn't quite work either

Answer (score 2):

The combination `apply` and `bitmap` doesn't work together because `bitmap` is not a function. Note that the entry in the documentation on `bitmap` says "Syntax" and not "procedure".

If `f` is a function, then `(apply f (list a b c))` will compute `(f a b c)`.
However, `bitmap` is not a function, it is a "special form".

You are in luck though, because `bitmap/file` is a function, so you can use that instead.

Answer (score 1):

I think it's worth understanding what `apply` is useful for, in Racket or other Lisp-1s.  In almost all code it is useful when you have a function and a bunch of arguments but you don't know how many there are, and you want to call the function with those arguments.  What that means in practise is:

- 'you have a function' so in particular you are not trying to evaluate some macro form or something else special;
- 'you have a bunch of arguments' means you have a list of arguments.

If you know how many arguments you have then there is almost never a reason to use `apply` unless the arguments are already in a list and you don't want to bother extracting them: `(apply cons l)` might be easier than `(cons (first l) (second l))` say.

In particular if you are trying to call a function with a single argument which you know then `apply` is definitely not what you want.  And similarly it is never what you want if the 'function' is a macro.

---

In Lisp-2s there is an additional use for `apply`: calling a function which is the value of a variable.  This is needed because, as a silly example, `(let ((x (lambda (...) ...))) ... (x ...) ...)` won't work in a Lisp-2.  Lisp-2s have an additional function, `funcall`, which does what `apply` does when you *know* the number of arguments: you don't need `funcall` in a Lisp-1.

---

The cases where `eval` is useful are even rarer.  There are some, but almost all the time it is at best a confusion and at worst a terrifying security problem: what does

```
(define (terror x) (eval `(list x)))
```

Do when it is called?  Answer: *anything at all that the language is capable of doing*: `(terror '(launch-the-nukes))`, say.